# How to compare two Hash maps whose values are class objects in a Junit Test case?

Tags: java, hashmap, junit4

```
public class TestFailure {

    @Test
    public void testSwitch() throws CustomException {
        Employee emp = new Employee(123, "John", "1234567890", "CEO", 0);
        Map<Integer,Employee> exhmp = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
        AllFunctions f = new AllFunctions();
        exhmp.put(123, emp);
        Map<Integer, Employee> htest= f.AddEmployee();
        assertTrue(exhmp.equals(htest));
    }
}
```

The test case comes out as a test failure even if the input from the console is the same as provided in the employee object. However, if different attributes of employee class are compared individually with htest, the test returns true.
The class  Allfunctions basically forms an employee object by asking details from the console and creates hashmap containing all the employee objects.

Comment: Have you overriden `equals` in your Employee class?

Comment: What is "AllFunctions" ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Wihtout knowing what AllFunctions is and does I can only guess what you are trying to achieve.

Hashmap#equals

> Compares the specified object with this map for equality.  Returns
>   true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings.  More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet()).  This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations
>   of the Map interface.

And Entry#equals will compare key and value using equals method of them. So if you have implemented the equals (and hashcode) method in your Employee class your code should work.